# Gruntjs reading settings from a custom json file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is a snippet from my gruntjs. I am passing the target via the command line parameter. The json file that I read into the settings contains configuration data that are needed by my tasks.

```
 grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            target: grunt.config.get('target'),
            settings: grunt.file.readJSON('config/' + grunt.option('target') + '.json'),
```

Here is a sample json file that I have.

```
{
    "property1": "http://localhost:60046",
    "property2": "cd98415a-7e9c-4206-86df-b93983769ef0"
}
```

How do I go about accessing values for property1 and property2 in my tasks?

I have been successful creating a helper function to read the json file and return the requested property value. But that involves reading the json file everytime a property value is requested.

I am trying read the json file once, store it in a config object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your setup is ok. You can access your properties in your tasks like this:

```
'<%= settings.property1 %>'
```